Android studio ladybird 2024 not detecting usb debugging mobile device in ubuntu 20.4
I have installed android adb tools in ubuntu and android studio 2024 in ubuntu. And i have done the mentioned also
https://askubuntu.com/questions/461729/ubuntu-is-not-detecting-my-android-device
But my Android studio is not detecting  my mobile device conned to the usb.

What should I do?
In ubuntu when is do a lsusb my device is there.
Tried many things but did not get the expected result

did you enable the developer option and choose the file transfer?

Yes developer option is on

even though developer option is on, android studio is not detecting device

Enabling Use Debugging option in Developer option detected device.

Try to re-write your comment more as an instruction: "Try to enable..." and make it clearer how to do what you are describing (where to configure the named option)

Enabling Use Debugging option in Developer option detected device.
